# using reference in for range in CPP

Tags: c++, for-loop, reference, constants, auto

if I only want to print int array in CPP  , what is the better impelemnt (and why) ?

```
for (const auto& x : { 1,2,3,4 })
{
    cout << x<< endl;
}
```

or

```
for (int x : { 1, 2, 3, 4 })
{
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

Comment: If you just want to `cout` then the latter is better in this case (primitive type), for non-trivial type then `const&`, and `&` if you want mutable object

Comment: For `int`s, the second is marginally more efficient - it's one less dereference per pass trough the loop, and copying an `int` is cheap.